# NODE_ENV=production with react-app-rewired

Tags: hadoop-yarn, production, react-app-rewired

I have installed `react-app-rewired` as dev dependency according to docs.

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    //...
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
  },
```

Now I'd like to make a production build. When I use

```
NODE_ENV=production yarn install
```

consequent `yarn build` says that `react-app-rewired: not found` (because it is in dev only).

1. Does `yarn build` implies production under the hood?
2. If so, why do I need all the dev dependencies to be installed to make a production build?
3. Should I get rid of NODE_ENV or move react-app-rewired to production then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making the production build (when you need to transform your code, generate built assets, etc.), you usually need to have the dev dependencies installed since the dev dependencies contain the build tools needed to transform/compile the code into production code. When running the actual production code that is built from running `yarn build`, then you'd only need to have the production dependencies installed.

So, before the app is actually built, you need to run `yarn install` without `NODE_ENV=production`. Once the app is built (i.e. once you've ran `yarn build` and you have all the code transformed, all artifacts generated, etc.), then you'd re-run `yarn install` but with production mode turned on (`NODE_ENV=production yarn install`) so yarn only installs the dependencies in the `dependencies` section of `package.json` (these are the dependencies that your transformed code would depend on, whereas the build tools like `react-app-rewired` are only needed at build-time).